# How to remove square brackets around the note field using Biblatex style=apa?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I use `biber` and `biblatex` with the `apa` style. It puts the note field in square brackets. Is it possible to remove the square brackets?
My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[british, english]{babel}   
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}  

\addbibresource{Literatur2.bib}
\begin{document}
some ext \parencite{WorldHealthOrganization.2020}
\newpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]
\end{document}
```

My bib-file:

```
@misc{WorldHealthOrganization.2020,
 abstract = {Fact sheet on family planning providing key facts and information on benefits of family planning, who provides family planning, contraceptive use, unmet need, contraceptive methods and WHO response.},
 author = {{World Health Organization}},
 year = {2020},
 title = {{Family planning/contraception methods}},
 url = {https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/family-planning-contraception},
 urldate = {2020-06-23},
  note = {Institute for the Study of Labor (IZA)}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These brackets are not in the usual Biblatex styles, so it's something special in the APA style. Looking in `apa.bbx` there is this definition:

```
% Additional post title information in brackets
\newbibmacro*{addinfo2}{%
  \printtexte[brackets]{%
    \iffieldbibstring{entrysubtype}
      {\bibcplstring{\thefield{entrysubtype}}}
      {\printfield{entrysubtype}}%
    \setunit*{\addsemicolon\addspace}%
    \printfield{note}}}
```

So if you want to change that you can redefine this (with `\renewbibmacro` to change an existing one) to a version without that `\printtexte`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[british, english]{babel}   
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}  

\addbibresource{Literatur2.bib}

% Almost as in apa.bbx
\renewbibmacro*{addinfo2}{%
  %% \printtexte[brackets]{%
    \iffieldbibstring{entrysubtype}
      {\bibcplstring{\thefield{entrysubtype}}}
      {\printfield{entrysubtype}}%
    \setunit*{\addsemicolon\addspace}%
    \printfield{note}
  %% }
}

\begin{document}
some ext \parencite{WorldHealthOrganization.2020}
\newpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]
\end{document}
```

which works. (But then, if you don't want or need the exact APA requirements, maybe you should use one of the standard authoryear styles instead? I haven't seen what APA says about these brackets, but I assume the style does it for an explicit reason.)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: I suggest you remove `\printtexte[]{` from `addinfo2` entirely. It does some quite tricky things behind the scenes to find out whether or not its argument contains something to print. Since `\printtexte` applies not formatting here that test is pointless.

Comment: OK, I have changed the answer according to that now. My aim was to keep the change as small as possible to maybe serve as a model for how you can find and change some other behaviour you want to change. I hope both versions work for that.